# How can I invoke a static method on a .NET object over COM interop?

Tags: .net, com, interop, com-interop

Is it possible to invoke a static method on a .NET Object, via COM interop?

I know I could write a wrapper class.   What if I don't wanna do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No you cannot do this.  COM interop communicates via objects, not types.

Work arounds I know of ...

- The best work around is to create a wrapper method on an instance to do the call on the type.  Yes this still requires an instance so it defeats the purpose but it's you're best option.
- Reverse PInvoke:  Still requires you to pass a function pointer down to the C++ layer

Comment: I could probably do this pretty simply with .NET 4.0 an the DLR magic, eh?

Comment: @Cheeso, not really.  Based on your problem statement it appears you are trying to find a solution to call from native -> managed code.  The DLR would only help a scenario where you were starting in managed code.

Comment: ah, I have to learn more about it.  I thought there was some magic Javascript-to-CLR integration coming.