# Is there a bitbucket in COM? Something like .NET's System.IO.Stream.Null?

Tags: .net, com, stream

I know about the [ADODB.Stream object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032(VS.85).aspx).

But what I really want is a Stream for which calls to Write() are no-ops.  Like [System.IO.Stream.Null](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.null.aspx).   I think `ADODB.Stream` is more like a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), which accumulates the data in memory.

And I cannot create an instance of `System.IO.Stream.Null` from COM, because it is a static property on the Stream class, thus [inaccessible from COM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395897/how-can-i-invoke-a-static-method-on-a-net-object-over-com-interop).  Or can I?  (without writing a wrapper class)

Comment: How do you want to use this null stream? ADODB.Stream implements IStream (COM's standard stream interface) as well as a scripting-friendly stream interface. Depending on which kind of interface you want to use, there are different options.

Comment: You can always open a real file stream to "nul:"

Comment: I want to use it within a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no default implementation like this. However, assuming that the code that needs this stream will use the [`IStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380034(VS.85).aspx) interfaces, you can take an existing instance of IStream and wrap it in your own implementation of `IStream`, with the `CopyTo/Write` calls implemented as a no-op. It should be relatively trivial to create a simple COM object for such a wrapper.