# Alternative for .NET's System.Convert within VBA

Tags: .net, vba, ms-access, com, com-interop

I'm writing a VBA function in Microsoft Access to Encrypt / Decrypt text data using RSA keys.

The following works currently:

```
CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider")
CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
```

but this is not working:

```
CreateObject("System.Convert")
```

I did some research and came across this stackoverflow question:
[Can I call a static method of a C# class from VBA via COM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24193183/can-i-call-a-static-method-of-a-c-sharp-class-from-vba-via-com)

So as it turns out, **System.Convert** is a static class so therefore it is unavailable to the COM object, and therefore unavailable to VBA.

I could wrap all my .NET stuff into my own class and then add it to Access as a reference, but its a little outside my comfort zone and I'd rather stay away from having to maintain custom references anyways for this specific project.

So rather than stay fixated on the System.Convert option, I thought about what my needs are specifically.  I need to be able to:

- Convert a Base 64 encoded string to a Byte Array and pass to .NET methods
- Convert a Byte Array, returned from .NET calls, into a Base 64 encoded string

The simplest option I see would be to write my own VBA code to convert between Base 64 and a byte array - however I see two pitfalls:

1. Encoding issues.  Converting between byte arrays and strings means having to deal with encoding issues.
2. Base64 variations.  Off the top of my head, the Base64 could have CR/LF in it. I am also not sure if Base64 encoded RSA strings would have / need to have a header.  If I wrote my own Base64 function, I would need to be sure that it is compatible with the RSACryptoServiceProvider's **FromBase64String** method.  I don't want to introduce extra characters into the encryption stream.

Given my concerns - Convert.FromBase64String seemed the best option since it keeps everything in .NET, but since I can't use it - I need an alternative.

If there were other standard .NET classes that provided the FromBase64String and ToBase64String functionality but were able to be instantiated via CreateObject - that would probably be the best option.  I do not know of any however.

Comment: .NET is a wrapper for the Windows API. System COM libraries are also a wrapper for the Windows API. There was a COM interface (CAPICOM) but it is only 32 bit. Instead use API calls https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379925(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I never realized that - but I never really thought about it either.  I guess because of all the CLR stuff that I had assumed it was something different.  This helps a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many *VBA/VBScript/VB6 Base64* implementations that generate exactly the same results as .NET `ToBase64String` for encoding and `FromBase64String` for decoding.

You can find a *VBA/VB6* example with full Base64 Encode and Decode functions here [Base64 encoder/decoder in Visual Basic](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/12.htm). The Base64 *VB* module bas file can be found here [Base64Coder.bas](http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/vbasic/Base64Coder.bas.txt).

Here are some screenshots from the same tests in `C#` and `VB6`. You can clearly see the results are the same for both languages:

**C#**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Check("Aladdin:open sesame", "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ=="); // example from RFC 2617)
    Check("1", "MQ==");
    Check("22", "MjI=");
    Check("333", "MzMz");
    Check("4444", "NDQ0NA==");
    Check("55555", "NTU1NTU=");
    Check("abc:def", "YWJjOmRlZg==");
    Check("????", "Pz8/Pw==");
    Check("abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz0123456789???", "YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbm1vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Pz8/");
}

private static void Check(string plainText, string base64Text)
{
    string s1 = Base64Encode(plainText);
    string s2 = Base64Decode(base64Text);

    Debug.WriteLine("String: " + s2 + ", to Base64: " + s1);

    if(s1 != base64Text || s2 != plainText)
        Debug.WriteLine("Check failed for \"" + plainText + "\" / \"" + base64Text + "\".");
}
public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}

public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
{
    var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
}
```

**C# OUTPUT**

[image: CSharp output]

**VBA/VB6**

```
Public Sub Main()
    Check "Aladdin:open sesame", "QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==" ' example from RFC 2617
    Check "1", "MQ=="
    Check "22", "MjI="
    Check "333", "MzMz"
    Check "4444", "NDQ0NA=="
    Check "55555", "NTU1NTU="
    Check "abc:def", "YWJjOmRlZg=="
    Check "????", "Pz8/Pw=="
    Check "abcdefghijklnmopqrstuvwxyz0123456789???", "YWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbm1vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXowMTIzNDU2Nzg5Pz8/"
End Sub

Private Sub Check(ByVal plainText As String, ByVal base64Text As String)
    Dim s1 As String: s1 = Base64EncodeString(plainText)
    Dim s2 As String: s2 = Base64DecodeString(base64Text)

    Debug.Print "String: " & s2 & ", Base64: " & s1

    If s1 <> base64Text Or s2 <> plainText Then _
        Debug.Print "Check failed for """ & plainText & """ / """ & base64Text & """."
End Sub
```

**VBA/VB6 OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

zou may you need this one

encryt with rsa sha256 sha1 md5 vbscript vba classic asp

https://github.com/ekede/WTS-Classic-ASP-MVC-Framework/blob/master/inc/class/crypt/rsa.asp