# How to pass API key in VBA for Get and Post Request?

Tags: vba, api

I am using https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/api/docs/ to access an API
I have my API key, however, i am not sure how to pass that from VBA. So far i tried below

```
AuthKey = [Key received]

With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False, authKey
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & AuthKey
        .Send
        response = .ResponseText
    End With
```

When i try from their test page https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/document/docs/document/id/content/fetchDocument.html it works well and when i goto dev tools that Authorization key is different, i think i am missing some encoding. Can someone please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.. i was missing to encode the key

```
Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String
  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  EncodeBase64 = objNode.text

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: So did you put  .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " &  EncodeBase64(AuthKey) ?

Answer (score 1):

Basic auth requires the username and password to be base 64 encoded together.  The AuthKey you need to pass is essentially:

```
def unencoded_auth = "[username]:[authkey]"
def encoded_auth = *call-to-base64-encode-value*(unencoded_auth)
```

Then you would replace

```
"Basic " & AuthKey
```

with

```
"Basic " & encoded_auth
```

I'll reference [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080840/alternative-for-nets-system-convert-within-vba) as to how to achieve the base64 encoding.