# Passing API key and parameters using VBA in a POST request

Tags: json, excel, vba, api, post

I have been trying to wrap my head around this VBA-Web doc http://vba-tools.github.io/VBA-Web/docs/ in order to pass auth_key and other parameters in a post request. I understand the concept of encoding the auth_key as explained here [How to pass API key in VBA for Get and Post Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185113/how-to-pass-api-key-in-vba-for-get-and-post-request). But I need help to include all the parameters below in VBA.

UPDATE:
I was able to make QHarr's code below work. But I'm still finding it hard to use my own curl parameters below. I've tried using EncodeBase64(apikey) but I'm not there yet.

```
Public Sub GetResults()
    Dim data As String, json As Object '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    data = "{""domainNames"":[""google.com""]}"
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "POST", "https://api.dev.name.com/v4/domains:checkAvailability", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " + _
            EncodeBase64("username" + ":" + "Token")
        .send data
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        Dim result As Object
        For Each result In json("results")
            Debug.Print result("domainName")
        Next
    End With
End Sub



Function EncodeBase64(text As String) As String


  Dim arrData() As Byte
  arrData = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)

  Dim objXML As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Dim objNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

  Set objXML = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
  Set objNode = objXML.createElement("b64")

  objNode.DataType = "bin.base64"
  objNode.nodeTypedValue = arrData
  EncodeBase64 = Application.Clean(objNode.text)

  Set objNode = Nothing
  Set objXML = Nothing
End Function
```

Here is the API doc - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/

Feature request:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-u "apikey:{apikey}" \
-d @parameters.json \
"{url}/v1/analyze?version=2019-07-12"
```

Example parameter:

```
{
  "features": {
    "semantic_roles": {}
  },
  "text": "IBM has one of the largest workforces in the world"
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Request.AddHeader`? Are you stuck on what the `-H`, `-u`, `-d` switches do, or asking someone to translate a `curl` command into VBA code? Are you also using Tim's VBA-JSON code? It should be useful for dealing with the JSON objects. Basically there's a lot to unpack here, and we don't know where your code stands with regards to everything that needs to happen for that request to work in VBA. Consider [edit]ing to add whatever VBA code you've got, so answerers know where you're stuck exactly.

Comment: I've added the VBA code where I'm stuck