# API/Authentication in http javascript

Tags: javascript, vba, api

I have been reading the following [document](https://dzone.com/refcardz/rest-api-security-1?chapter=12) regarding Rest API's which was incredibly useful, however it doesn't give any information in the actual implementation of it.
I have a successful, incredibly basic js on a Wix website.

```
   import {response, serverError, ok} from 'wix-http-functions';

   export function get_Hello() {
   let options = {
    "headers": {
        "Content-type": "application/json"
        }
    };
    options.body = {
     "items": "hello world"
   }
   return ok(options);
  }
```

Say if my API key is "key" and my API value is "value, how do I put that into js file?
I imagine it goes in the header, but can't quite figure it out as I'm not very good at js!

I am calling the above function in VBA with the below code:

```
Dim http As Object, JSON As Object
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "myurl..blah/functionname", False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send
    response = .responseText
End With

MsgBox (response)
```

I imagine to use the api key and value from the call I would `.setRequestHeader` with the key and value?

Thanks in advance if anyone has the time to help

Comment: Did you try that?  It all really depends on exactly what the API expects (ie. how it's configured) - there is no "universal" method.

Comment: Do I need to make 'headers' an array or is it a different variable e..g headers: content type and headers: authorization - both just being 'sub values' of headers? Have you seen API's with keys and values in the header? I see a lot of examples with 'basic' authentication, 64 encoded, but none with an actual API value and key in the header. Feel like I'm out of my depth with all of this!

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50185113/how-to-pass-api-key-in-vba-for-get-and-post-request   If you control both ends of the process then it's up to you how you want to set up your authentication/access control.